# Java null pointer exception al añadir a un ArrayList

Tags: java, arraylist, nullpointerexception

Me tira `NullPointerException` en el metodo `procesaInformacion`, cuya función es añadir los parametros introducidos por el usuario y crear un `ArrayList` con ellos.

```
private void bAlumnoActionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt) {                                        
    String nombre=nombreIntroducido.getText();
    String apellido=apellidoIntroducido.getText();
    int nºexp=Integer.parseInt(nºexpIntroducido.getText());
    float primeraNota= Float.parseFloat(primeraIntroducido.getText());
    float segundaNota= Float.parseFloat(segundaIntroducido.getText());
    float terceraNota= Float.parseFloat(terceraIntroducido.getText());
    int añoNac=Integer.parseInt(añoIntroducido.getText());
    DatosAlumno nuevoAlumno= new DatosAlumno(nombre,apellido,nºexp,primeraNota,segundaNota,terceraNota,añoNac);
    gestora.procesaInformacion(nuevoAlumno);
}
```

Aqui esta el metodo `procesaInformacion`, donde `DatosAlumno` es un objeto de la clase que contiene la informacion a introducir en el `ArrayList`

```
public void procesaInformacion(DatosAlumno a){
     this.add(a);       
}
```

Comment: ¿Podrías incluir el código en el que inicializas u obtienes la variable `gestora`? Ese error se da porque `gestora` es nulo.

Comment: Vale, no he inicializado gestora bien, gracias por hacerme dar cuenta del error de novato jajaja

Comment: Perfecto! ¿Puedo ponerlo como respuesta y me la aceptas? :)

Comment: Siiii lo estaba intentando hacer yo jajaj es q es la primera vez que uso esta pagina

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Lo más probable es que no hayas inicializado correctamente la variable `gestora` y eso te esté dando un `NullPointerException`.

Comment: Buenas por favor mejora tu respuesta, ve [¿Cómo escribo una buena respuesta?](https://es.stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-answer) para que la comunidad te entienda mejor y sea realmente aceptada.